# LastLogonDate AD property for computer object - how often is it refreshed?

Tags: windows, active-directory

I was not able to find any good enough information about this. How often should this value be refreshed for windows servers which are online all the time? Seems like it's many days??

example to get this:

```
Get-ADComputer hostname -property *|select LastLogonDate
```

Answer (score 5):

LastLogon is updated on the domain controller where the authentication occurs at every logon.  LastLogon is not replicated to other domain controllers.

lastLogontimeStamp (what you are querying) is not updated on every logon, but is replicated to other domain controllers. By default it can be as much as 14 days out of date.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works/

Comment: OK so now I am thinking which domain controller it is for each server where this would be updated... The one in the same site? If there would be only one site it would be on PDC emulator?

Comment: It should be on the one which is in variable %logonserver% right?

Comment: @Vitas: %logonserver% that you see may be for your user account. May not necessarily be the same that the computer used for authentication.

Comment: does this lastlogondate mean computer actually becomes online and communicate with DC?  or it means some user has to logon the computer so that this attribute get updated?